# Use of いける in this sentence

Tags: translation, potential-form

> 戦術{せんじゅつ}と戦闘{せんとう}どっちも**いける**奴{やつ}には勝{か}てない。

The translation of this seems to be

> (He) will not win against someone who can do both strategy and fighting

However this is the first I've seen いける used to mean "can do".  I would have understood どっちもできる, so am I translating correctly? Else in what context can one be substituted for the other?

Comment: See meaning 1 of the third word in this link http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%84%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 7, accepted):

行{い}ける vs. いける

When a common word that is usually written using kanji is written in kana, you can be 99% sure that it is being used for its "new" and/or colloquial (sometimes slangy) meaning.

So, 「行ける」 means "to be able to go", but 「いける」 means something else.  What does it mean, then?  Let us quote from [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%84%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B-431655#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89).

> 動{どう}カ下一{しもいち}］《行{い}くことができる意{い}から》
>
> １ 相当{そうとう}にうまくできる。「歌{うた}だけでなく、踊{おど}りも―・ける」
>
> ２ 相当の量{りょう}の酒{さけ}が飲{の}める。「なかなか―・ける口{くち}だ」
>
> ３ 飲食物{いんしょくぶつ}の味{あじ}がよく、おいしい。いただける。「ここの料理{りょうり}はちょっと―・ける」

That briefly translates to:

> 1 To be able to perform quite well
>
> 2 To be able to drink in large quantities
>
> 3 To taste good.  Tasty, delicious.

So, the word has very positive meanings.

> 「戦術{せんじゅつ}と戦闘{せんとう}どっちもいける奴{やつ}には勝{か}てない。」

thus means:

> "***It is hard to beat a guy who is very good at both strategy and (actual) fighting***."

Comment: Couple of follow up questions.  First I see it's written "―・ける"  is this natural or a dictionary thing?  Second, you're saying it's a slangy expression?  Third, unrelated, I'd heard 奴 as an insulting way to refer to someone, for example "あのやつ".  Is that true or is it just "あの" that makes it insulting?

Comment: `あのやつ` <- I think you'd rather say あいつ...

Comment: @Andrew 1)  "―・ける" is a dictionary thing. You are to read it as いける.  2)  Not slangy, just colloquial in this case.  I mean both in your example sentence and the dictionary definitions I quoted.  However, if you surround いける with other words that clearly sound slangy, いける might also sound slangy as a result.  3) 奴 (or あいつ), all by itself, is not insulting.  It is just colloquial/informal and tough-guy-like.  You can actually refer to a person that you look up to using those words.

Comment: @chocolate Yes, that too, but I would never call anyone 奴 because it could offend.  But then when I lived in Japan I didn't hang out with many "tough guys".  :)

Comment: Question~ Is いける potential form of 行くor is it a different verb? Isn't 行く godan and 行けるichidan? Is it the same?  Is it ok for me to use 行きる in the sentence provided?

Answer (score 3):

Your translation is correct, but I would say that "(He/you) cannot win".

In everyday language I have seen this use of いける way more than once. I would say it feels more natural, while here できる feels more scholastic.

Comment: I left out the first part of the sentence where the subject (some guy referred to as "メガネ") was mentioned, since it wasn't relevant.  So definitely informal.