# What is the meaning of the word "イケた"?

Tags: translation, meaning, manga

The word wasn't in any sentence, the person simply said that one word in the speech bubble. Here's the context situation if it's any help:

Guy: //kisses girl

Guy:  お (Oh)

Guy: イケた

Girl: ?! (Suprised reaction)

Answer (score 4):

[いける](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%84%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B/) is a kind of slang (that's why it's often written in katakana) that has a wide range of meanings by itself. This site previously [had a question on this word](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42045/7810) (which is more general), but I can guess with high confidence that, in the particular context you have provided, it means "tried and succeeded". What he means by "try" is still ambiguous from the portion of context, but there'd be two reasonable interpretations:

- He was not sure if he was able to do such a thing, but he actually was
- He was not sure if she let him do such a thing, but she actually did

So it should be like:

> *kiss*
>   Guy: お *Oh*
>   Guy: イケた *Success!*
>   Girl: ?!